# mvc3 RegularExpression block word

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, filter

I have a MVC3 model and a textbox that accepts some html it works perfectly, but how can I filter the 2 words **www** and **porn** as there are some people that are constantly writing that,my model is

```
   [AllowHtml]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([^<]|<em>|</em>|<u>|</u>||a z|A Z|1 9|)*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character")]

    public string mytextbox { get; set; }
```

So that above works correctly user's can put in HTML only using em and u . As stated above how can i filter the worlds **www** and **porn** . I been looking everywhere but haven't found how to do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead, like:

```
^(?!.*(?:www|porn))(?:[^<>]|<em>|</em>|<u>|</u>)*\z
```

The rest of your expression was useless, so I removed it. Note that you have to get the encoding right when doing filtering like this. And there could be other ways around it.

It will also match any words which include `www` or `porn`. If you don't want that you could add some `\b`s.